# Retain content on Page1 after navigating to Page2 and back to Page1 in WPF

Tags: wpf, navigation

On Page1 I have a `TextBox`, `ComboBox` and `Hyperlink` control. The `TextBox` has a value "ABC" and the `ComboBox` has a value "123".

When I click on the `Hyperlink` on Page1 I navigate to Page2.

On Page2 I click on a back `Button` which takes me back to Page1.

I can actually see my values. However I cannot see the values when the controls on Page1 are bound to a data source.

If I have XAML like this:

```
<TextBox: x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Path = uName}" />
```

then in the Page1 navigation to Page2 and back it is not retaining the values in the `TextBox` and `ComboBox`.

Is this some kind of intended behaviour or a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you remembered to set  `KeepAlive="True"` in Page1 XAML?